# How to deserialize an array containig strings and objects in JSON.NET

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net, serialization, json.net

I am trying to deserialize a special array to an object in Visual Basic.
The following json data is delivered by the webservice I use; the part interesting to me is the "data" property; basically it is an array of string arrays, with each array representing an object:

```
{"timestamp":1385984969075,
"data":
[
  [1590,null,null,null,0],
  [1020,"data a",null,null,0],
  [1025,"data b",null,null,0],
  ...
  [2756,"data c",null,
    [
      {"id":2,"name":"Tom","mail":"tom@test.te","f_id":6,"md":1},
      {"id":3,"name":"Carl","mail":"carl@test.te","f_id":6,"md":1}
     ]
  ,3],
  [1277,"data d",null,null,0],
  ...
  ]}
```

In this example, data item 4 of each array may be either null or contain an array of objects.

I would like to deserialize the array into a list of objects, but I can't get it to work. I have searched through a lot of similar posts, but I could not find anything helpful so far.

(I am writing in Visual Basic.net , but C# examples are welcome.)

Can someone help please?

Comment: I deserialized to a list of strin array. This approach worked at first, because initially I had no answers with an object array in it.

I used
Dim answer As New contactGetAnswerObject
answer = CType(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(conn.serverResponse, GetType(contactGetAnswerObject)), contactGetAnswerObject)

Public Class contactGetAnswerObject
   Public Property timestamp As Long
   Public Property data As List(Of string())
End Class,

Comment: Have you written this webservice yourself that produces that JSON? why can't you simply have a model object class that you can create a list/array of object from?

Comment: No, I did not write the webservice myself.
The output of the web service is variable; you have to send a list of the required properties in your service request. Then you receive an array containing an array of the the required properties for each item matching the request.

Comment: BTW: I am new to the json.net package, so please forgive me if I am not seeing the obvious.

Comment: Post your classes you're mapping this JSON data Too.

Comment: Forgive me if I am wrong, but this would be of no help I guess; the data object is huge, just a class with a few dozen string properties and 3 or 4 object properties.
But I am writing becaus I cannot directly deserialize to this object, for the json is in array/list format.
Please clarify.

Comment: @rootusertom I have written an answer below. I hope it can help you. Make sure you check how I have desearlized the array of arrays in the people class, I think this is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Updated:***

Here is another example that uses object arrays to map that the array of arrays you have. I have then extracted each piece of data within the arrays.

Again hopefully this will help you:

```
var list = new People
        {
            PersonList = new object[]
            {
              new object[]
             {
               "Test1", "Test2", "Test3", null, new object[]{new Person{Name="John", Age=21}}, 1
             },
              new object[]
             {
               "Test4", "Test5", "Test6", null, null, 2
             },
             new object[]
             {
               "Test17", "Test8", "Test9", null, new object[]{new Person{Name="Sara", Age=31}}, 3
             },
                new object[]
             {
               "Test10", "Test11", "Test12", null, null, 4
             },
             new object[]
             {
                 "Test13", "Test14", "Test15", null, new object[]{new Person{Name="John", Age=31}}, 5
             }
             }
        };

        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);

        var objList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<People>(output);

        objectList = objList.PersonList;

        foreach(JArray objectItem in objectList)
        {

            var stringOne = (string)objectItem[0];
            var stringTwo = (string)objectItem[1];
            var stringthree = (string)objectItem[2];
            var nullObj = objectItem[3];

            foreach(var individual in objectItem[4])
            {
                JObject obj = (JObject)JToken.FromObject(individual);
                var person = obj.ToObject<Person>();

                string name = person.Name;
                int age = person.Age;
            }
            var num = (int)objectItem[5];
        }
```

JSON:

```
{
"PersonList": [
    [
        "Test1",
        "Test2",
        "Test3",
        null,
        [
            {
                "Name": "John",
                "Age": 21
            },
            {
                "Name": "Pete",
                "Age": 44
            }
        ],
        1
    ],
    [
        "Test4",
        "Test5",
        "Test6",
        null,
        null,
        2
    ],
    [
        "Test17",
        "Test8",
        "Test9",
        null,
        [
            {
                "Name": "Sara",
                "Age": 31
            }
        ],
        3
    ],
    [
        "Test10",
        "Test11",
        "Test12",
        null,
        null,
        4
    ],
    [
        "Test13",
        "Test14",
        "Test15",
        null,
        [
            {
                "Name": "John",
                "Age": 31
            }
        ],
        5
    ]
]
```

}

Person Class:

```
 public class Person
{
    public string Name { set; get; }

    public int Age { set; get; }
}
```

PeopleList class:

```
 public class People
{
    public object[] PersonList { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort! Alas, it does not help me. Your code does serialize and then deserialize an array of objects. But there is no pure object array in my example. It is rather an array containing strings and one object (which also may be null).

Comment: I would write a CustomCreationConverter, but I do not fully unterstand the mechanism. Is there a good example or tutorial you know of?
Is it like I "plug into" the deserialization function of a certain type (string array in this case) and write my own code for it?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much again for your effort! I have translated your example code to VB.NET (please note that the first block with the definition of the 'list' object has to be one line in the Visual Studio; I have just formatted it for better overview):

```
Dim list = New People With {.PersonList = 
        New Object() { 
            New Object() {"Test1", "Test2", "Test3", Nothing, New Object() 
                   {New Person With {.Name = "John", .Age = 21}}, 
            1}, 
            New Object() {"Test4", "Test5", "Test6", Nothing, Nothing, 2}, 
            New Object() {"Test17", "Test8", "Test9", Nothing, New Object() 
                   {New Person With {.Name = "Sara", .Age = 31}}, 
            3}, 
            New Object() {"Test10", "Test11", "Test12", Nothing, Nothing, 4}, 
            New Object() {"Test13", "Test14", "Test15", Nothing, New Object() 
                   {New Person With {.Name = "John", .Age = 31}}, 
            5} 
        } 
    }

    Dim output As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list)
    MessageBox.Show(output)

    Dim objList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of People)(output)

    Dim objectList As Object() = objList.PersonList

    For Each objectItem As JArray In objectList
        Dim stringOne As String = CStr(objectItem(0))
        Dim stringTwo As String = CStr(objectItem(1))
        Dim stringThree As String = CStr(objectItem(2))
        Dim nullObj As Object = objectItem(3)
        For Each individual As Object In objectItem(4)
            Dim obj As JObject = DirectCast(JToken.FromObject(individual), JObject)
            Dim person As Person = obj.ToObject(Of Person)()
            Dim name As String = person.Name
            Dim age As Integer = person.Age
        Next
        Dim num As Integer = CInt(objectItem(5))

    Next
```

Basically this approach is what I am trying to do right now. I just thought there had to be a more elegant way (no offense intended!) using JSON.NET.
To my mind the great drawback is the list of type casts in the for-each loop; my data object has about 110 properties with two of them having sub-objects with 10 properties each. Also there are 3 or 4 other data objects in my project with of least haf the size.

So my idea is to write a function that derives the property type from the target object and then do the type casts more or less automatically. I have a list of property names for the web service call, so this list can be used to find the property name corresponding to a response item.

Anyway I will have a look on jArray and jObject, for I have not used these so far.

Comment: if my code got you on the right track and answered the question feel free to mark my answer as correct. Glad it could help.